# /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/cwchar:44:10: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory

Tags: compiler-errors, fatal-error, wchar

I'm trying to compile the c++ file and it's throwing error that wchar is not present
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/cwchar:44:10: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory